# How do I pass an incrementing counter into a partial when not rendering from an instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a partial: `views/nodes/_node.html.erb`, which I render on any view like so:

```
<%= render @nodes %>
```

When I render it like that, per the Rails Guides, I can use `node_counter` within the partial as a counter to keep track of various elements within the partial (or say assign an ID that increments every time the partial is rendered).

Now I want to use this same partial, but not rendered like that but rather like this:

```
<%= render partial: "nodes/node", locals: {node: event.eventable} %>
```

When I do that, I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `node_counter' for #<#<Class:0x007fa3b6ca9778>:0x007fa3b58a60c8>
```

That is because I never specified/passed `node_counter` as a local variable.

So how do I specify `node_counter` to start at 0 and always increment every time this partial is rendered - if I can't do it the Rails Way?

For reference, the Rails Guide says this:

```
Rails also makes a counter variable available within a partial called by the collection, named after the member of the collection followed by _counter. For example, if you're rendering @products, within the partial you can refer to product_counter to tell you how many times the partial has been rendered. This does not work in conjunction with the as: :value option.
```

Comment: Can you show the `render` in context of your view?  If you are rendering each of something, you can use `each_with_index` to generate an index you can then pass to your partial.  I can post a complete answer if this is your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your calling view, you can use `each_with_index`:

```
<% @foo.each_with_index do |foo, index| %>
  <%= render 'nodes/node', f:foo, node_counter:index %>
```

Then in your `_nodes/node` partial, `node_counter` will increment starting at 0.

The reason that `node_counter` is not available for you in your second call is that you are calling the partial with a member, not a collection.

Comment: Brilliant. Just what I wanted. Muchas Gracias!